# Router on vanilla JS for SPA that uses history api?

Tags: javascript

I need a vanilla js router for a spa site. [Here](https://github.com/thecreazy/create-a-modern-javascript-router) on the github I found it seems like an ideal implementation, but there is one problem. This implementation, and everything that I found on the Internet, works well only with hash, through the history api that I need, they refuse to work, tell me what I'm doing wrong, or tell me another working implementation.

So I just take the [Router](https://github.com/thecreazy/create-a-modern-javascript-router/blob/master/src/Router.js) class code, and set the routes I need:

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  root: '/'
});

router
  .add('', () => {
    console.log('deafult page');
  }).add('settings', () => {
    console.log('settings page');
  }).add(/task-list/, () => {
    console.log('task-list page');
  })
```

And only the `console.log('deafult page')` is executed, if I enter `http://localhost:3000/settings` in the line, then it will give me `Cannot GET /settings`
if i use click event

```js
document.addEventListener('click',()=>router.navigate('settings'))
```

then the link will become `http://localhost:3000/settings`, but the code `console.log('settings page');` will not work

Comment: Your server needs to be enabled for spa routing

Comment: @DanielA.White I use webpack, can you tell me what settings i should add?

Comment: It’s not a webpack configuration

Comment: @DanielA.White oh THANK YOU SO MATCH, i solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add webpack settings

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: './dist',
  port: 3000,
  historyApiFallback: true, // its enable SPA routing through historyApi
}
```